# Mule anypoint studio throws error while importing the zip projects

Tags: mule

I am getting below error while importing the `.zip` file to Anypoint studio workspace.

```
Unable to create or initialize project
Unable to get effective rights from ACL - The operation completed successfully.
```

Windows version - 8

JDK - 1.8

Anypoint studio 5.1

Comment: As far as I know, Mule still needs JKD 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permissions of the zip file before importing, especially if this zip has been obtained from a download site or an email. Right click (on windows), check properties > Security.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have admin rights for C:\windows\Temp folder.